# could not implement drag and drop between js tree and jq grid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jstree

i want to implement js tree and jq grid   with drag and drop feature 
now my   code is :
**grid**:

```
  afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
        $("#" + rowid).addClass('jstree-draggable');
                alert('hi');
    },
```

and in **js tree**:

```
"drag_finish" : function (data) { 
                alert("DRAG OK"); 
                $.ajax({
                     async: false,
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: "/Home/FolderTree",
                     data: {
                            "path": data.o.attr('id'),
                            "destination": data.r.attr('id')
                     },
                     success: function (r){
                     }
                });
              }
```

I have tried but not could not able to  done.I also want to drag and drop from our computer file system to jq grid row and js tree folder ,can  you  share any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you must set gridview property to false in jqgrid in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from long time of research ,I used `gridview:true`  but in jq grid   to make drag and drop ,you have to set  property  as below in jq grid configuration

```
gridview:false
```